# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 64-bit Nvidia GTX 780 Issues

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.10

so im new to linux of any kind, i have just made the leap and switched from windows to ubuntu. It took me a while as i wanted a system that was clean and had tons of support for issues like this, i chose the Gnome Ubuntu.

Anyway when i was first trying to install ubuntu, i would get past bios, it would load the first ubuntu screen asking for a live "try it" session or to install. From here no matter the option i chose there was little to no display output. all i would get would be a black screen with a cursor.

So i removed my GTX 780 from my system and ran my HDMI cable to my monitor via the motherboard onboard intel graphics. This works perfectly. Now i am assuming this is a driver issue, and so i went hunting once i has installed ubuntu for nvidia graphics drivers for linux based systems and installed the latest version that directly supported the Nvidia GTX 780 cards. This made it worse. I would boot to find a screen flashing between a light grey with a box and a black 'no display input' screen. I had to re install ubuntu using my usb and no graphics card installed all over again...

I am now back to square one with no graphics card installed running off my Intel' HD on board graphics. The drivers failed to work, maybe i did something wrong? Any advice to fix this?

Cheers :)

My System specs:

CPU: Intel i5-4690K
MOBO: Asus Z97-A
Mem: 16GB G-Skill 1600
HDD: Raid 0 2 x 120gb SSD's
HDD: 2TB Seagate Barracuda
GPU: Asus GTX 780 Direct OC CU II 3GB
Cooler: Corsair H80i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing ubuntu please try this
*`ctrl+alt+t`*
Then in termnal try
*`sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`*
Then 
*`sudo reboot`*
and done